# Is there a free resource to track a specific plane's upcoming routes?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, airlines, aircraft

Sometimes there's a specific plane I'd like to try and fly on, if given the opportunity. For example, in the Qantas fleet, there's [VH-XZP](http://www.aussieairliners.org/b-737/vh-xzp/vhxzp.html), painted as the "Retro Roo". But it doesn't always do the same routes.

Is there a way to see where it's scheduled to fly in the upcoming days? I'm only aware of sites that [show past history for a plane](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/VHXZP), or paid systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flightradar24](https://www.flightradar24.com) can do this but often only shows the next few flights, and doesn't seem to have any data at all for the plane in your case. But some aircraft such as [G-EUYT](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/g-euyt) can show their future flights around 36 hours before departure. Do consider that any number of unexpected issues could potentially cause the aircraft operating a flight to change, and this only becomes more likely the further in advance you'r looking.